# List comprehension performance is incredibly slow and maintains hold on resources

Tags: performance, angularjs, list-comprehension

In AngularJS, I'm using a list comprehension to loop over the properties of an object, and this happens 50 times in a particular resultset:

```
<div class="property-value" ng-show="property.type == 'object'">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(k, v) in property.value"><span class="property-name">{{k}}:</span> {{v}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What happens is when I run the query, the HTML generation time for this takes several seconds and then maintains a hold on performance even after the HTML is rendered. When I comment the list comprehension out, the performance issue completely goes away.

What would cause resources to be tied up after the template is rendered? Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do here without the performance penalty?

Comment: Could you provide a plunker? How deep is property.value?